# Create FileUpload from code behind

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I need to create a FileUpload control from the code behind page. I have this function:

```
Private Function CreateUpload() As FileUpload

Dim txtFileUpload As New FileUpload
txtFileUpload.ID = "element1"
Return txtFileUpload

End Function
```

However, even though I successfully use a similar technique for other form controls, my FormUpload doesn't get rendered to the page.

Can someone please explain what I'm doing wrong.

Edit: I'm writing the returned FileUpload to a DIV on the page outside of my function.

**Update**: It's sorted. Seemed to be a problem with Visual Studio. Closing it, relaunching and then rebuilding the website sorted it. Thanks to all who responded.

Thanks.

Comment: We need more detail. First of all, this code only declares a new FileUpload control but never adds it to the page. Second of all, we don't know where this code is called. It may be too late in the Page lifecycle to dynamically add a control to the page.

Comment: I'm writing the control to the page outside of the function. I'm calling it in exactly the same way as all my other form element controls and they work ok, so it's nothing to do with the Page lifecycle.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see you adding this control to the WebForm. Try adding it:

```
Private Function CreateUpload() As FileUpload

    Dim txtFileUpload As New FileUpload
    txtFileUpload.ID = "element1"
    Page.Controls.Add(txtFileUpload)
    Return txtFileUpload

End Function
```

or if you don't have access to the Page inside this function add it when you call the function in the code behind of your webform:

```
Dim txtFileUpload As FileUpload = CreateUpload()
Page.Controls.Add(txtFileUpload)
```

Comment: Thanks, Darin, but I'm adding the control outside of the function. I'm using pretty much exactly the same technique for adding other controls such as textboxes etc so I know that side of things is sorted. I was wondering if I needed to 'tie' the FileUpload to a textbox or similar?

Comment: @chut319, no you don't have to tie it to anything. Adding it to the Controls collection of the page should be sufficient. Just make sure that you are doing this at the right time of the [page lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) which is the `PreInit` event.

Comment: I closed Visual Studio, reopened it, rebuilt the website and boom, it's there. No code changes at all. Very frustrating! Thank you for your help anyway, @Darin.